# Getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when use templateUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

When I change my website to use templateUrl, I get an error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
>   app/views/flights-no.html:1:24 caused by: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'flights',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/flights-no.html' // cause error
  //template: "<h1>pelo tempa</h1>" <-- This works
})
export class AppFlights { }
```

flights-no.html

```
<flights>
    <h1>Gooooooo!</h1>
</flights>
```

[image]

package.json

```
 ...   
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",

        "systemjs": "0.19.27",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.17",
...
```

**Note** I don't know if is relevant or not. This is a C# MVC website.

Comment: Can you try removing `<flights>` tags from html file. Just keep your `<h1>` tag and see what happens.

Comment: Can you explain to me a little more @Sanket.

Comment: yes.. look at the answer below

Comment: essentially, you have a directive `<flights>` which is drawing a template, seeing `<flights>` in the template, drawing a new template, seeing `<flights>`, drawing the template, etc., until the system runs out of memory, giving you `<flights><flights><flights><flights>.....</flights></flights></flights></flights>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **flights-no.html**

From

```
<flights>
    <h1>Gooooooo!</h1>
</flights>
```

to

```
<h1>Gooooooo!</h1>
```

Because of your html, it is going recursive. Hence, you are receiving Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

If you want reproduce error in simple quick-start tutorial, simply try this one-

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<my-app></my-app>'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```